# ProcessCpuUsage class - Resources Monitor

Tags: c#, uwp

I want create Resources monitor as UWP application. I read a lot about performanceCounter class from System.Diagnostics but... this class is not contain to UWP. Then i read about some native classes but my skill is too low to implement this yet ;/.

Then i found ProcessCpuUsage class Windows.SystemDiagnostics; and i tried implements this class but i cant find info about constructors and i dont know how implements it? What info can i get from this class ?

In my app i need string with cpu/ram usage, and info about free disk space, and i want to show it as widget. Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

[**ProcessCpuUsage**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.diagnostics.processcpuusage.aspx) class has no constructor, it provides access to data about the CPU usage of a process. And this class only has a [**GetReport**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.diagnostics.processcpuusage.getreport.aspx) method, which gets the [**ProcessCpuUsageReport**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.diagnostics.processcpuusagereport.aspx) for the process. With `ProcessCpuUsageReport` class, we can get [**KernelTime**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.diagnostics.processcpuusagereport.kerneltime) and [**UserTime**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.diagnostics.processcpuusagereport.usertime) consumed by the process.

To get a `ProcessCpuUsage` object, we need use [**ProcessDiagnosticInfo.CpuUsage**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.diagnostics.processdiagnosticinfo.cpuusage.aspx) property. This is one of the properties in [**ProcessDiagnosticInfo**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.diagnostics.processdiagnosticinfo.aspx) class. This class provides diagnostic information about a process, such as CPU usage, disk usage, memory usage and so on. And `ProcessDiagnosticInfo` class has two static methods: [**GetForCurrentProcess**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.diagnostics.processdiagnosticinfo.getforcurrentprocess.aspx) and [**GetForProcesses**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.diagnostics.processdiagnosticinfo.getforprocesses.aspx) that help us to get the `ProcessDiagnosticInfo`.

However, please note that these two methods can only **get the `ProcessDiagnosticInfo` related to your own app**. `GetForProcesses` method can return a list of `ProcessDiagnosticInfo` objects for all running processes. But here the "all running processes" means all running processes in the same App Container. For example, for a UWP with [out-of-process background tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task), `GetForProcesses` method may return several `ProcessDiagnosticInfo`s including running background tasks. But for a simple UWP app, it may always return one `ProcessDiagnosticInfo`. This method can't return diagnostic informations for all running processes in the computer/device as UWP apps are running in app containers and isolated from each other.

So if you are going to create a resources monitor application, UWP may be not a good choice. Classic desktop apps might be better for your scenario.

Comment: Is there a way to get a report of CPU and other resources of the whole system?